# portrait orientation in layout of qgis.3.2.0(bonn)

Tags: qgis, cartography, qgis-3

How to set a map in portrait orientation in layout of qgis.3.2.0(bonn).there is no option in  layout view for changing the orientation of paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your page then select page properties, this will activate the item properties tab where you can set the orientation and size of the page